# How do I know if IIS is really Compressing my HTML?

Tags: iis, gzip

Our IIS server has Dynamic and Static HTML Compression enabled, but when I browse to our website and view the Response Headers in Fiddler, I only see the "Content-Encoding: gzip" header for one resource (a flash file).

Why would the other response types not have this header?  Does it mean that compression is NOT working for the other responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like our company network was actually stripping out the Content-Encoding header. (I have no idea why). When I browse from home the gzipping seems to work fine. [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/187859/iis7-is-gzipping-files-but-not-serving-the-gzipped-version) on StackExchange.com helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be 100% sure that compression is active is to compare the size of the downloaded resource against the original file on the server. The network tab of the Firebug extension can help you here.

Comment: The Net tab on firebug says that my page is over 900KB, close to what I get if i save it to disk and view the file size. So I'm guessing compression is not working?